# video player & video menu plugin

Tags: html, video

May you recommend a plugin or something to be able to have something like this: http://www.apple.com/iphone/videos/#tv-ads-busyday but with youtube video?

IN DETAIL: Show thumbnails of my youtube videos, when you pick a video it should play on the top of the page.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=Show+thumbnails+of+my+youtube+videos

Comment: try to work on your reading comprehension... I know it can be achieved by using almost any jquery gallery plugin, but as there are plenty of them I would appreciate recommendation from more experienced ppl.